# Bad user experience - needs looking at

Tags: discussion, support, status-deferred, review

The question referred to was rapidly re-opened, but this meta isn't about one specific question being closed as a dupe; it's about the user experience once that happens.

---

I'm a big boy now. I can handle the knock-backs, but imagine this was a new user.
I don't often ask questions on SU, so don't often get to see what the experience is as an asker.

I ask this question…

[Simple Windows 10 view of any process preventing Sleep?](https://superuser.com/questions/1576236/simple-windows-10-view-of-any-process-preventing-sleep)

Within a few minutes it's closed as a dupe.

1. It is absolutely not a dupe. the linked question totally fails to answer the question as asked.
2. The user info banner is of absolutely zero use.
   [image]

As a new user it tells me the question has already been asked and has an answer… which it doesn't.

As an experienced user, I'd like to know who closed it… no info at all, there. Was it a gold badge with dupe-hammer privs, an admin, or did 5 other regular users think it was a dupe, all inside 5 minutes?
*After comments* I now realise I can see this in the new timeline feature [which I'd forgotten existed] - however I gained that knowledge from comments in here, I had no guidance to it from the question page or closed banner.

It gives me the opportunity to edit.
It doesn't tell me **why** I might want to edit it.
Once edited it still tells me nothing. It doesn't tell me about the Review queue. it gives no hint as to what process I might face to have it re-opened, or if such a process even exists. Nada. Just throws you right back to where you were.

Once edited… the Edit button is still there, so what do I do next?
Wander off never to return, after hitting 'Delete question' in a huff?

Or maybe do I go back to the only bit of hopeful info… "ask a new one"…
which we all know as experienced users will be closed inside 5 minutes as being a dupe of this one.

That is overall a very bad user experience.

Comment: Can you see the [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/1576236/timeline)?

Comment: I can. I never thought to look there - it was a gold badge dupe-hammer. I'm still very worried at the user experience… if even a 25k+ user doesn't immediately see the picture of 'whu' happ'n'

Comment: I didn't want to say who it was if it wasn't accessible to you :)

Comment: I've reopened it for you ...

Comment: Thank you. I should still leave this meta Q here because that really wasn't a good user-experience, even for an oldie. A new user would have just walked away or ranted in comments, etc.

Comment: Man, I never thought I'd get to status-review tag anything from here :D.

Comment: More seriously, relevant meta posts https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394871/upcoming-feature-new-question-close-experience  and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396754/question-close-updates-phase-1 . No idea why its on MSO rather than MSE, other thats around the time things were getting shifted around

Comment: OK - that's a lot o' readin'. I'll have to have a proper look later. thanks for the links, I'd never have thought to look on SO. I was in two minds as to whether to post this here or 'main' meta anyway.

Comment: Main meta. I think that was in the tail end of the dislike of main meta, though throwing the status-review tag means in theory a CM would looking at it. [I believe this comes under a barrier to participation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350799/358125)

Comment: The change is documented here, in the edit from Kristina - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/284336 It includes the explanation for why we made the decision we did. We can revisit but there is a technical reason for it.

Comment: Also related:  [Duplicate explanation should encourage improvement of original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166525/195817),  [Make it clear that making an edit will cause the post to be reviewed for reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332499/195817#332504 "How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?")  and  [Remove the suggestion to post a new question from the closed questions post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951/195817) (on MSE).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for raising this. I agree that this is not a good user experience and there's a ton of room for improvement when it comes to how we handle dupes, especially with how we communicate feedback to post authors when there are potential areas with a post to address. We plan on revisiting the overall question closing and feedback experience [after we get through the next few months of our roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), and we'll share more about that work once we get started on it. Adding [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) to this for now.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. My question suggested no fixes, as I doubt it's one click-of-the-fingers to fix. I thought just to highlight the negative experience & hope that ever-vague *"someone"* could take it further. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tetsujin You're welcome - this is also very personally important to me. I don't think anyone needs to have such a negative experience getting feedback about their post, and I think the current system is set up in a way that makes it feel very difficult for it to feel otherwise. More to come!